# How do I stop a window.setInterval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that is called every 2000ms.  I want to stop this so I can have the user do other things on the page without it being called again.  Is this possible?  Here is the function that gets called every 2000ms:

```
window.setInterval(function getScreen (sid) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getScreen.php?sid="+<?php echo $sid; ?>,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    },2000);
```

Comment: This is a DoS vulnerability right here. What if your XMLHttpRequest takes longer than 2 seconds (due to traffic/load)? You'll stack up requests and risk bringing down the server. Consider reading [this](https://www.zcfy.cc/original/why-i-consider-setinterval-to-be-harmful-zetafleet) article and use timeouts (with or) proper scheduling instead.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There's no built-in "pause" function, but you can stop it, and then start a new interval with the same function.

First, you need to capture the id returned by the call to `setInterval`:

```
let intervalId = window.setInterval(...);
```

Then when you want to stop it, call

```
 window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```

In your case I'd suggest defining `setScreen` by itself, and not inside of the call to `setInterval`. This way you can just use `intervalId = window.setInterval(setScreen, 2000)` when you want to resume it.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using jQuery I would recommend the plugin [jQuery Timer](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer)

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
  alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
}, 2000, true);
```

Then you can easily pause the timer:

```
timer.pause();
```

And also resume it:

```
timer.play();
```

Answer (score 16):

It's easier to do this by using `window.setTimeout()` instead of `window.setInterval()`. The following is adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout/3969760#3969760).

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/Hkzex/

Code:

```
function RecurringTimer(callback, delay) {
    var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

    this.pause = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
        remaining -= new Date() - start;
    };

    var resume = function() {
        start = new Date();
        timerId = window.setTimeout(function() {
            remaining = delay;
            resume();
            callback();
        }, remaining);
    };

    this.resume = resume;

    this.resume();
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I managed to add a start up from pause delay quite easily. The Timer version you also have on github seems more like the perfect answer for the op though. TY!

Answer (score 5):

You can't pause an interval, but you can stop it and restart it.

```
var timer = setInterval(xx,tt);

// then some time later
clearInterval(timer);
```

You just have to capture the return value from `setInterval()` and call `clearInterval()` on it when you want to stop it.

The other way to do a repeat that you can stop repeating at any time is to do a repeated `setTimeout()` and then `clearTimeout()` to stop the next timer or just don't kick off the next `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 3):

### Do not re-declare anything

Simply add a class that tells the interval not to do anything. For example: on hover.

```js
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function() { //declare new function
  if(!$('#counter').hasClass('pauseInterval')) { //only run if it hasn't got this class 'pauseInterval'
    $('#showCount').html(i++); //just for explaining and showing
  }
}, 500);

$('#counter').hover(function() { //mouse enter
    $(this).addClass('pauseInterval');
    $('#counting').text('Stopped counting...');
  },function() { //mouse leave
    $(this).removeClass('pauseInterval');
    $('#counting').text('Counting...');
  }
);
```

```html
<!-- you'll need jQuery for this. If you really want a vanilla version, ask -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="counter"><span id="counting">Counting...</span> | <span id="showCount"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `setInterval()`, **especially when dealing with network (XHR/fetch) calls.** There is no guarantee that your request will be finished on time but `setTimeout()` won't wait to fire up the next one opening more and more connections.

Simply use a setTimeout() that, with a simple if statement reschedules itself.

```js
function updateContent() {
    someFunctionReturningAPromise()
        .then(() => {
            if (continue) {
                setTimeout(updateContent), 2000);
            }
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

updateContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(code);
window.clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.