# Javascript like confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, webbrowser-control

I tried using several jquery message pluggins such as [alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/).

But the main thing I noticed is system message boxes halt the background functionality until user responds. Other pluggins don't have this functionality.

Is there a way to get this function to jquery pluggins? May extending native javascript objects? I cannot think a way myself.

Could you give me some idea? 
How can I stop current procedure until the user clicks a button?

Comment: [`showModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog)?

Comment: @Teemu : seems it is deprecated. But thanks

Comment: @Teemu: At the top it says it's deprecated, but at the bottom it says it's part of the HTML5 standard... do you know what's going on there?

Comment: @FelixKling I've no idea... It was just few years ago sMD came up also other to browsers than IE. Though it's not the official part of the standard _yet_.

Comment: It is usable for this case. But why they say it is deprecated?

Comment: @shan: It might have been deprecated at some point...

Comment: @Reinder Wit : Will it freeze setInterval() function too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) has some excellent samples available

You can choose to freeze the background by setting 'modal' to 'true':

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ modal: true });
```

jQuery will not pause any `setInterval()`, but you can [hook up to events](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open), so you will probably be able to stop them from executing code yourself.

Check out this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m3b2/1/) that does just that...

Comment: Will it freeze setInterval() function too?

Comment: the problem is that I have several setIntervals(), if I clear them, I will be in trouble. How can I pause them when the open event triggered?

Comment: In the code that executes after the interval has past, check for a global boolean value which you can set to true/false when handling the dialog. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval

Answer (score 2):

I am using jquery alert for "alert", "prompt" and "confirm" and it's really very good. I am mentioning reference URL for you.

http://runnable.com/UfNMPnKMU1ZgAACQ/how-to-create-custom-jquery-alert-confirm-and-prompt-dialogs

you can change look and feed as per your design.

Comment: This is something like I wanted. I will try. Thanks @Rachit Patel

Comment: Thanks Shan, If answer help you then please up-vote my answer so other user can use it.

Comment: sorry my purpose is not met by this either :-(