# Timer does not actually stop after pause button is clicked

Tags: javascript

Timer is displayed as if it is kind of stop after pause button is clicked, but when i click resume i find out that counter continue to countdown behind the scene. I guess there are issues with setInterval. Please help me. My project on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/NdqQXm) for reference if you need.

My timer function

```
function timer(seconds) {
  clearInterval(countdown);
  const now = Date.now();
  const then = now + seconds * 1000;
  displayTimerLeft(seconds);
  console.log({
    now,
    then
  });
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      const remainSeconds = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
      if (remainSeconds < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        return;
      }
      displayTimerLeft(remainSeconds);

    }
  }, 1000);

}
```

Pause and start click events

```
pause.addEventListener('click', function() {
  isPaused = true;
  return;

})

start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  isPaused = false;
})
```

Comment: A few pointers. First, don't use 'then' as your const. 'then' is a keyword in js, used in 'if then' statements. When js takes issue with an item, it often skips the rest of the function, so changing your variable name might fix it. Although, you should also use 'variable = undefined' whenever your use clearInterval(variable), otherwise it won't kill it all the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Pausing setInterval()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval)

Comment: @bobjoe It is not a duplicate actually, the problem comes from him not using a variable to countdown seconds but instead keeping the end timestamp unchanged even when paused. His code snippet is almost exactly the same as the answer in the post you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference of the current time and manually add a second at each tick.

```
function timer(seconds) {
  clearInterval(countdown);
  const t = new Date();
  const end = t.getTime() + seconds * 1000;
  displayTimerLeft(seconds);
  console.log({
    t,
    end
  });
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPaused) {
      const remainSeconds = Math.round((end - t.getTime()) / 1000);
      if (remainSeconds < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        return;
      }
      displayTimerLeft(remainSeconds);
      t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 1);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Demo: http://codepen.io/miguelmota/pen/wgMzXY**

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your code, I suppose the problem is you keep the same `then` value, which is ultimately a timestamp at which the timer should end. Right now, instead of pausing the countdown, you stop the display from changing.

I would advise using your variable `seconds` instead (and calculating display using modulo %), and decreasing it every second. That way, pausing the display would effectively pause the decreasing.

Answer (score -2):

`setInterval` returns a unique id that can be used to stop the timer using `clearInterval`:

```
var id = setInterval(function(){
console.log('running every 300 ms');
},300);

clearInterval(id) // stop timer
```

Comment: This would work, but then additional code is needed to resume the interval on unpause.