# Javascript adding a pause option to countdown timer not working

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I have a javascript function to countdown a timer. So I want to add pause option to this function. I tried this way,

```js
function countdownTimeStart() {

 var el = document.getElementById('demo');
 var pause= document.getElementById('pause');

 var time = [10,10,10];

 var x = setInterval(function () {

  var hours = time[0];
  var minutes = time[1];
  var seconds = time[2]--;

  if (time[2] == -1) {
      time[1]--;
      time[2] = 59 }

  function pauseTimer() {
    savedTime = time;
    clearInterval(x);
  }
  pause.addEventListener( 'click', pauseTimer);

  if( seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0 ){
    clearInterval(x);
    el.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
  } else if (seconds < 10) {
    el.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
  }

}, 1000);

}

countdownTimeStart();
```

```html
<button id="pause" class="pause">Pause</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

The countdown timer working correctly. But the pause option not working. So how can I correct this script. Can someone help me.

Comment: `addEvecancel.ntListener( 'click', pauseTimer);` Spelling matters.

Comment: I converted your code to a working snippet (replacing your time with an array of prefilled values instead of reading it from an input, but in essence its the same) and it seems to be working.

Comment: Yeah now its working ! So how can I resume it when pause button click again. Could you please add this as an answer, I can marked it as the correct answer. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your code is working, I would like to note a couple of things: adding your pause handler inside your `interval` isn't a good idea, you will be adding a pause handler *every interval*, so in the end you are just stacking up the amount of functions to handle when clicking. I have made your button toggle and separated out the event listener into a handler function so you can attach it to any button. These changes will keep your code working fluently while also making it easier to understand:

```js
function initCountdown() {
  
  function event_click( event ){
    
    // If our interval is null, we need to start the counter
    // And also change the innerText so its obvious what the button will do next
    
    if( interval === null ){
      
      start();
      event.target.innerText = 'pause';
     
    } else {
      
      pause();
      event.target.innerText = 'start';
      
    }
    
  }
  
  function start(){
    
    // First use pause() to be sure all intervals are cleared
    // it prevents them from doubling up
    
    pause();
    interval = setInterval( count, 1000 );
    
  }
  function pause() {
  
    clearInterval( interval );
    interval = null;
    
  }
  function count(){
    
    // By doing this before declaring your variables
    // you make it so the variables actually hold the new calculated values.
    
    time[2]--;
    
    if( time[2] == -1 ){
    
      time[1]--;
      time[2] = 59;
      
    }
    
    // Lets use some cool new syntax here to reduce the amount of code needed
    // this will destructure an array assigning their indexed values to the index of the variable
    
    var [ hours, minutes, seconds ] = time;

    if( seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0 ){
    
      clearInterval( interval );
      
    }
    
    // We always want to print something, and if the values are 0
    // the output is still the same, so lets seperate that.
    
    if (seconds < 10) {
    
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
      
    } else {
    
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
      
    }
    
  }
  
  // Lets also clearly name our things.
  
  var outputElement = document.getElementById('demo');
  var toggleElement = document.getElementById('toggle');
  var interval = null;
  var time = [10,10,10];

  // Add event listener once
  
  toggleElement.addEventListener( 'click', event_click );
  toggleElement.click();
  
}

initCountdown();
```

```html
<button id="toggle">start</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Update** Adding a cancel button:

```js
function initCountdown() {
  
  function event_click_cancel( event ){
    
    pause();
    time = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
    print();
    
  }
  function event_click_startpause( event ){
    
    // If our interval is null, we need to start the counter
    // And also change the innerText so its obvious what the button will do next
    
    if( interval === null ){
      
      start();
      event.target.innerText = 'pause';
     
    } else {
      
      pause();
      event.target.innerText = 'start';
      
    }
    
  }
  
  function start(){
    
    // First use pause() to be sure all intervals are cleared
    // it prevents them from doubling up
    
    pause();
    interval = setInterval( count, 1000 );
    
  }
  function pause() {
  
    clearInterval( interval );
    interval = null;
    
  }
  function print(){
    
    // I have separated out the print function as we want to use it
    // in the count and the cancel function
    
    var [ hours, minutes, seconds ] = time;

    if( seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0 ){
    
      clearInterval( interval );
      
    }
    
    if (seconds < 10) {
    
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
      
    } else {
    
      outputElement.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
      
    }
    
  }
  function count(){
    
    // By doing this before declaring your variables
    // you make it so the variables actually hold the new calculated values.
    
    time[2]--;
    
    if( time[2] == -1 ){
    
      time[1]--;
      time[2] = 59;
      
    }
    
    print();
    
  }
  
  // Lets also clearly name our things.
  
  var outputElement = document.getElementById('demo');
  var toggleElement = document.getElementById('toggle');
  var cancelElement = document.getElementById('cancel');
  var interval = null;
  var time = [10,10,10];

  // Add event listener once
  
  toggleElement.addEventListener( 'click', event_click_startpause );
  toggleElement.click();
  
  cancelElement.addEventListener( 'click', event_click_cancel );
  
}

initCountdown();
```

```html
<button id="toggle">start</button>
<button id="cancel">cancel</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: According to my requirement I want to resume the counting when click the pause button again. Isn't it possible ?

Comment: @Chathurika Yes, it is, let me make a small adjustment!

Comment: great one solution

Comment: Thank very much for your answer, really helpful.

Comment: @Chathurika I have amended my solution to add a toggle, again, separated out since it makes your code more reusable and honestly, more readable and maintainable. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly I really appreciate your help & great job

Comment: @somethinghere I tried to add a cancel option to here, but then script will not working, can't I use a cancel option here?

Comment: @Chathurika What is your cancel supposed to do? Is it a separate button that resets the timer? That removes the timer? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is a separate button, when it is click,the time should be 00:00:00 by stopping the counting

Comment: <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>

Comment: @Chathurika I have updated my post with an example of cancelling. This made me separate out the `print` function, as we now want to use it somewhere else than just in the timer.

Comment: Thank you great job

Comment: @somethinghere there are some problems of this script that I couldn't solve by myself. This countdown time function goes through the minus value too.So I want to stop counting when it 00:00:00, Could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: @Chathurika This is getting further outside the scope of the question and it feels like I am just doing this project for you. However, the counter stops at zero in my testing so I am not seeing that issue.

Comment: Yeah you are correct, I'll fix it by myself. Thank you.