# Set Pause option to Javascript Countdown Timer script

Tags: javascript, countdown, pause

I'am creating a countdown timer.So this is the my code so far.

```
function countdownTimeStart() {

var el = document.getElementById('demo');
var cancel = document.getElementById('cancel');

/* Start count the time in timer panel */
var time = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
time = time.split(':');

var x = setInterval(function () {

    // set hours, minutes and seconds, decrease seconds
    var hours = time[0];
    var minutes = time[1];
    var seconds = time[2]--;

    console.log(time);

    // create a function to handle the cancel
    function cancelCountdown(){
        el.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
        clearInterval(x);
    }
    // attach listener to cancel if cancel button is clicked
    cancel.addEventListener( 'click', cancelCountdown);

    // if seconds are negative, set them to 59 and reduce minutes
    if (time[2] == -1) {
        time[1]--;
        time[2] = 59
    }

    // if minutes are negative, set them to 59 and reduce hours
    if (time[1] == -1) {
        time[0]--;
        time[1] = 59
    }

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    if( seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours == 0 ){
        clearInterval(x);
        el.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    } else if (seconds < 10) {
        el.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
    }

}, 1000);}
```

So I want to create a pause button for this. I refered similar questions such as [Javascript - Pausing setInterval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval).

It seems that it is easy to create pause option in jquery. But I haven't idea how can I apply this to my script. Can someone help me.

Comment: Save time when interval started, cancel interval upon button click, calculate time interval should have, start new interval upon till calculated time ends

Comment: Could you please show the way as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: The only significance of jQuery in the answer you linked to is in adding event handlers to a couple of buttons that set a `pause` flag to be true or false -- nothing that's really special to the idea of pausing a timer. As long as you know how to add event handlers without jQuery, the answer is there.

Answer (score 1):

On pause click, you could create an object like `savedTime` that saves the current value of the `time` array. Then, when `start` is clicked, you could check to see if there is anything in `savedTime`. If so, then assign `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` to the value of that object; otherwise, set their values to the default ones from the input. For example, something like:

```
var el = document.getElementById('demo');
var cancel = document.getElementById('cancel');
var savedTime;
function countdownTimeStart() {
  /* Start count the time in timer panel */
  var timeValue = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
  var time;
  if (savedTime) {
    time = savedTime;
    savedTime = null;
  } else time = timeValue.split(':');

  var x = setInterval(function () {
    // set hours, minutes and seconds, decrease seconds
    var hours = time[0];
    var minutes = time[1];
    var seconds = time[2]--;

    // rest of countdownTimeStart is as normal
    // ...
  });

  // Attach this function to your pause button:
  function pauseTimer() {
    savedTime = time;
    clearInterval(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, shouldn't I add  " var pause= document.getElementById('pause');  ?

Comment: As the comment says, you need to `Attach this function to your pause button:` - you didn't post your HTML so I left that to you.

Comment: <button id="pause" class="pause">Pause</button> is the my pause button and is it possible to add  only " var pause= document.getElementById('pause');" additionally from your code,

Comment: You also need to attach the click handler to the button - just declaring the element won't do anything.

Comment: It works fine. Can I resume it when click the pause button again?

Comment: It's currently set up to resume when `countdownTimeStart` is called. If you want clicking on the pause button to resume it, then you'll have to change `pauseTimer` to check to see if `savedTime` is populated. If it is populated, then resume (that is, call `countdownTimeStart`); otherwise, assign to `savedTime` and clear the interval.