# how to stop setinterval when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm using a slideshow on my website, the plugin doesn't have an autoplay option so I'm using setinterval to achieve it.

here is my Code :

```
var myInterval,
    startInt = function(){

        myInterval = setInterval(function(){

            $(".slidenav__item--next").click();

        }, 7000);

    };

startInt();
```

I have a video overlay that open when clicking on an element, what I'm trying to do is to stop my autoplay function when the overlay is opened, and start again when closing the overlay.

here is what I've tried sofar but it's not working :

".slides a" is the link to open my overlay, ".back" is the link to close it.

```
var myInterval,
    startInt = function(){

        myInterval = setInterval(function(){

            $(".slidenav__item--next").click();

        }, 7000);

    };

startInt();

/* RESET WHEN OVERLAY OPENED */

$(".slides a").click(function() {

    clearInterval(myInterval);

});

$(".back").click(function() {

    startInt();

});
```

Any help higly appreciated !

thanks

Comment: are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: no error. the autoplay still running

Comment: The variable definition is in a reachable scope for the other functions?

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML as well. You can use Stack Snippets (icon like `<>`) to get the HTML and JavaScript (and CSS) working together to illustrate the problem. As it is, it's hard to tell where the code is going wrong.

Comment: Add a console.log in each event handler to check if they are both getting called at the same time. I imagine the ".slides a" selector might match the back button as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Pausing setInterval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using a flag :

```
var paused = false;
var autoplay = window.setInterval(function() {

    if(!paused) {

        $(".slidenav__item--next").click();

    }

}, 7000);

$('.slides a').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    paused = true;

});

$(".back").click(function() {

    e.preventDefault();
    paused = false;

});
```