# I want to develop a java script code by which i use space bar to pause the setInterval function

Tags: javascript

The function is not running after I include the function to pause the `setinterval` function using the space bar

```
if(event.keyCode == 32 ){
            clearInterval(timerId);
```

Comment: Are you listening for keyboard inputs - please provide more context

Comment: please share more code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277900/javascript-pausing-setinterval are relevant to your problem

Answer (score 5):

> All you are looking is to add an [eventListner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the DOM,which can
>   listen to key press events of keyboard

```js
   
// adding eventListner to he document for keypress event
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {

  if (event.keyCode == 32) {  // if the spacebar (keycode 32 is pressed)
    clearInterval(myVar);  // clear the interval
  }

})

// Setting the Intevral here
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. The OP doesn't know enough to even post an attempt so they can't really be expected to understand code with zero comments, documentation or explanation. Also, the code doesn't illustrate pausing, but stopping/cancelling it.