# How to add progress bar (timeline) to slider like slides or nivoslider

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, slideshow, timeline

I want to add a progress bar to a JavaScript slideshow (like [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/) or Nivoslider).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout), which covers some of what I need, but I can;t intergrate it into my slideshow.

[Here is an example of what I'm after.](http://www.spotnil.com/envato/codecanyon/li-slider/)

For example, when I focus the slideshow (or click pause button), timeline and slider will be paused, and I can resume (when I move out).

Here is the code I have so far:

```html
<div id="products_example">
    <div id="products">
        <div id="slides_timeline"></div>
        <div class="slides_container">
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-3-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-1-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-2-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 2 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-4-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 4 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-5-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 5 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-6-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 6 2x"></a>
            <a href="http://www.zappos.com/pro-keds-royal-plus-lo-grey" target="_blank"><img src="img/1144953-p-2x.jpg" width="366" alt="1144953 P 2x"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-3-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 3 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-1-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 1 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-2-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 2 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-4-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 4 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-5-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 5 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-6-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 6 2x"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/1144953-p-2x.jpg" width="55" alt="1144953 P 2x"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('#products').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
        effect: 'fade',
        slideSpeed:300,
        crossFade:true,
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        generateNextPrev: true,
        generatePagination: false,              
        play: 5000,
        hoverPause:true,
        animationStart: function(){animateTimeline();}, // Function called at the start of animation
        animationComplete: function(){}, // Function called at the completion of animation
        slidesLoaded: function() {} // Function is called when slides is fully loaded
    });
});

////reset timeline
function resetTimeline(){
    var timeline = $("#slides_timeline");
    timeline.css({width:'0'},0);
}

////animate timeline
function animateTimeline(){
    var timeline = $("#slides_timeline");
    timeline.stop().css({width:'0',opacity:1},0);
    timeline.stop().animate({width:'100%'},5000,'linear',function(){$(this).animate({opacity:0,width:0})});
}

$("#products .next,.pagination li a").click(function(){
    resetTimeline();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple different ways you can do this but from a high level here is what I would do:

Every single one of these types of slideshows whether you make it or not uses basically a setInterval function and you are clearing the timer or pausing it when you mouse over. So you have access to a variable someplace within the function that specifies the number of milliseconds you want each slide to show before it moves on and the setInterval fires a function that moves to the next slide. I would access this variable and then use it to drive the jquery rotate plugin which you can micro control the rotation of using the milliseconds in the slider function.

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

If you want a progress bar style like the one in your example you would basically need to convert the number of milliseconds for each slide into a percentage something like: (current / total milliseconds) * 100 and then apply that as the percentage width on the progress bar to make it look like it's animating across.