# JavaScript Timer Pause

Tags: javascript, timer

The code is below. How would you set a button to pause the timer and resume when pressing resume? The // marks below are where I'm placing my pause and resume tags. Thank you for all of your help!!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(1,0,0);

function f(){
var h= d1.getHours();
var m= d1.getMinutes();
var s=d1.getSeconds();
m= (m<10)?"0"+m: m;
s= (s<10)? "0"+s : s;

var el= document.getElementById("inputid");
el.value= h+":"+m+":"+s;
d1.setSeconds(d1.getSeconds()-1);
if( h==0 && m==0 && s==0 ) clearTimeout(t)
var t= setTimeout("f()",1000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="text" id="inputid"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">f()</script>

//pause and resume buttons would go here.
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop a timeout with `clearTimeout()` passing it the return from `setTimeout` or, in your case `t`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tJWmH/

Another pointer: dont pass a string to `setTimeout`, instead pass a function reference, so:

```
var t = setTimeout(f,1000)
```

in place of

```
var t = setTimeout("f()",1000);
```

if you're wondering why, search for ["eval is evil".](https://www.google.com/search?q=eval+is+evil)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is: when the buttons is pressed, set a variable like `paused`.  In your `f` function, if paused is true, simply return immediately.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if (paused) return;
  // update the dom
}, 1000);
```

input

```
<input type="button" value="Pause" onClick="window.paused=true" />
```

[Here is a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fW5CD/)

Comment: the resume button sets `paused=false`

Comment: Think you'd need to change this to a `setInterval` otherwise the function wont be rescheduled if you pause.

Comment: No, setTimeout is also ok, he clears the timeout only if the counter reaches zero (there also needs to be an else branch). So that is ok. See my answer to your question!

Answer (score 1):

This is not my code. I found it and use in my projects. Here's the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3969760/1250044

```
Timer = function(callback, delay) {
  var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

  this.pause = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    remaining -= new Date() - start;
  };

  this.resume = function() {
    start = new Date();
    timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
  };

  this.resume();
};
```

use:

```
var t = new Timer(function(){
 /* ... */
}, 500);

t.pause();
t.resume();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(1,0,0);
var t;


function f() {
    var h= d1.getHours();
    var m= d1.getMinutes();
    var s=d1.getSeconds();
    m= (m < 10) ? ('0'+m) : m;
    s= (s < 10) ? ('0'+s) : s;

    var el= document.getElementById("inputid");
    el.value = h+":"+m+":"+s;

    if( h==0 && m==0 && s==0 ) {
        clearTimeout(t)
        return;   
    }
    d1.setSeconds(d1.getSeconds()-1);

    t= setTimeout(f,1000);

}

function pause() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}
function resume() {
    t= setTimeout(f,1000);
}
resume();
```

You just call pause() to pause it, and resume() to resume it. That's it! 
Notice that I am calling resume() once, just to start the counter.

EDIT: You must check if it reached zero before decrementing, and return so that pressing resume won't continue to work.