# Pause and resume setInterval

Tags: javascript

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  //do stuff
}, milisec);
```

Is there a way to stop this interval at will, and to resume it from where it lasted? Say, code runs every 5 sec. I stop it in the middle of the 2nd second, when resumed, I want it to run the remaining 3 seconds and continue to run afterwards every 5 sec. again.

Comment: javascript is single threaded, `setInterval` statement just instructs the event loop to execute a function(first argument) after a fixed time in millis(second arg) and returns immediately.

Comment: I was thinking of clearInterval(), but not sure exactly how to get remaining time, resume it from there and allow it to continue.

Comment: Well store the current time when calling `setInterval`, and compare it to the then current time when your “stopping” of the whole process occurs.

Comment: But how do I resume the interval to run for the remaining seconds, and then resume the interval to run for the initial timer?

Comment: Have a look at [javascript: pause setTimeout();](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3969475/218196) ... it should be easy to adept it to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

1- when you want to `pause` the timer, calculate the remaining milliseconds and store it somewhere then call `clearInterval`.

2- When you want to `resume` the timer, just make a call to `setTimeout` passing the remaining time stored in the previous step as the argument.

3- And in `setTimeout`'s callback you should call `setInterval` again.

UPDATE: This is what you want, a changed version of [javascript: pause setTimeout();](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969475/218196) thanks to @Felix Kling

```
    function IntervalTimer(callback, interval) {
        var timerId, startTime, remaining = 0;
        var state = 0; //  0 = idle, 1 = running, 2 = paused, 3= resumed

        this.pause = function () {
            if (state != 1) return;

            remaining = interval - (new Date() - startTime);
            window.clearInterval(timerId);
            state = 2;
        };

        this.resume = function () {
            if (state != 2) return;

            state = 3;
            window.setTimeout(this.timeoutCallback, remaining);
        };

        this.timeoutCallback = function () {
            if (state != 3) return;

            callback();

            startTime = new Date();
            timerId = window.setInterval(callback, interval);
            state = 1;
        };

        startTime = new Date();
        timerId = window.setInterval(callback, interval);
        state = 1;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var timer = new IntervalTimer(function () {
        alert("Done!");
    }, 5000);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        timer.pause();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            timer.resume();
        }, 5000);
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 6):

To piggyback off Alireza's answer, here's an ES6 class that does the same thing with a bit more functionality, and doesn't start right away. You can set a maximum number of times the timer will fire off before automatically stopping, and pause and resume any number of times before the next time it's set to fire off.

```
export default class IntervalTimer{
  constructor(name, callback, interval, maxFires = null){
    this.remaining = 0;
    this.state = 0; //  0 = idle, 1 = running, 2 = paused, 3= resumed

    this.name = name;
    this.interval = interval; //in ms
    this.callback = callback;
    this.maxFires = maxFires;
    this.pausedTime = 0; //how long we've been paused for

    this.fires = 0;
  }

  proxyCallback(){
    if(this.maxFires != null && this.fires >= this.maxFires){
      this.stop();
      return;
    }
    this.lastTimeFired = new Date();
    this.fires++;
    this.callback();
  }

  start(){
    this.log.info('Starting Timer ' + this.name);
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.proxyCallback(), this.interval);
    this.lastTimeFired = new Date();
    this.state = 1;
    this.fires = 0;
  }

  pause(){
    if (this.state != 1 && this.state != 3) return;

    this.log.info('Pausing Timer ' + this.name);

    this.remaining = this.interval - (new Date() - this.lastTimeFired) + this.pausedTime;
    this.lastPauseTime = new Date();
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
    clearTimeout(this.resumeId);
    this.state = 2;
  }

  resume(){
    if (this.state != 2) return;

    this.pausedTime += new Date() - this.lastPauseTime;
    this.log.info(`Resuming Timer ${this.name} with ${this.remaining} remaining`);
    this.state = 3;
    this.resumeId = setTimeout(() => this.timeoutCallback(), this.remaining);
  }

  timeoutCallback(){
    if (this.state != 3) return;

    this.pausedTime = 0;
    this.proxyCallback();
    this.start();
  }

  stop(){
    if(this.state === 0) return;

    this.log.info('Stopping Timer %s. Fired %s/%s times', this.name, this.fires, this.maxFires);
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
    clearTimeout(this.resumeId);
    this.state = 0;
  }

  //set a new interval to use on the next interval loop
  setInterval(newInterval){
    this.log.info('Changing interval from %s to %s for %s', this.interval, newInterval, this.name);

    //if we're running do a little switch-er-oo
    if(this.state == 1){
      this.pause();
      this.interval = newInterval;
      this.resume();
    }
    //if we're already stopped, idle, or paused just switch it
    else{
      this.interval = newInterval;
    }
  }

  setMaxFires(newMax){
    if(newMax != null && this.fires >= newMax){
      this.stop();
    }
    this.maxFires = newMax;
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw your answer just now. That's great dude. Thanks :)

Comment: This is awesome, but `resume()` resets `this.fires`, which breaks the max fires functionality.

Comment: this.log.info does not work on the browser. I suppose this is a server-side function?

Comment: @viv yes it's a custom logger.  Replace with console.log or your logging of choice on the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need setTimeout with a go and stop - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/QjdUR/1/

```
var cnt = 0;
var fivecnt = 0;
var go = false;

function timer() {
    if(!go)
        return;
    cnt++;
    if(cnt >= 5){
        cnt=0;
        everyFive();
    }
    jQuery("#counter").text(cnt);
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}

function everyFive(){
    fivecnt++;
    jQuery("#fiver").text(fivecnt);
}

function stopTimer(){
    go = false;  
} 
function startTimer(){
    go = true;
    timer();
}
```

Comment: There is a reason why we don't want answers that only link to jsFiddle. Is it really so difficult to include and explain the code in the post itself?

Comment: Thanks, You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

```js
let time = document.getElementById("time");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
let playButton = document.getElementById("play");

let timeCount = 0,
  currentTimeout;

function play_pause() {
  let status = playButton.innerHTML;
  if (status == "pause") {
    playButton.innerHTML = "Resume";
    clearInterval(currentTimeout);
    return;
  }
  playButton.innerHTML = "pause";
  stopButton.hidden = false;
  clearInterval(currentTimeout);
  currentTimeout = setInterval(() => {
    timeCount++;
    const min = String(Math.trunc(timeCount / 60)).padStart(2, 0);
    const sec = String(Math.trunc(timeCount % 60)).padStart(2, 0);
    time.innerHTML = `${min} : ${sec}`;
  }, 1000);
}

function reset() {
  stopButton.hidden = true;
  playButton.innerHTML = "play";
  clearInterval(currentTimeout);
  timeCount = 0;
  time.innerHTML = `00 : 00`;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="time">00 : 00</h1>
  <br />
  <div>
    <button onclick="play_pause()" id="play">play</button>
    <button onclick="reset()" id="stop" hidden>Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).