# Stopping , the timer function in an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Clearing the `setInterval` from console I tried using

```
clearInterval(obj.timer())
```

this seems not be doing the trick any idea peeps

```js
var obj = {
  timer: function timer() {
       setInterval( () => { console.log('welcome') },1000)
  }
}

obj.timer()

// how do I clearInteval from the console
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pause and resume setInterval in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395724/pause-and-resume-setinterval-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store id returned by the `setInterval` function.

```
 var obj = {
    id: null,

    timer: function timer() {

        this.id = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('welcome');
        }, 1000)
    },
    stop: function stop() {
        clearInterval(this.id);
    }
}
obj.timer();
```

you can stop the timer by calling stop function `obj.stop()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this, add "return" into function

```
var obj = {
            timer: function timer() {
                 return setInterval( () => { console.log('welcome') },1000)
            }
           };
var timer = obj.timer();
//clear timer
clearInterval(timer);
```