# How do i add a Play/Pause button for this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, slide

Hi im trying to make a slideshow that run automatically and with this code it's working but i need to add a Play/Pause button to that code. Someone care to help ?
I would need the html/css also

```
var indexDiaporama=1;
afficherDiapo(indexDiaporama);

function ajoutDiapo(n){
afficherDiapo(indexDiaporama+=n);
}

function diapoActuelle(n){
afficherDiapo(indexDiaporama=n);
}

function afficherDiapo(n){

var i;
var slides=document.getElementByClassName("diapo");
var dots=document.getElementByClassName("dot");

if(n>slides.length){indexDiaporama=1;}

if(n<1){indexDiaporama=slides.length;}

for(i=0; i<slides.length; i++){

slides[i].style.display="none";
}

for(i=0; i<dots.length; i++){

dots[i].className=dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
}

slides[indexDiaporama-1].style.display="block";

dots[indexDiaporama-1].className+="active";
}

var timer = setInterval(function(){
indexDiaporama++;
afficherDiapo(indexDiaporama);
},3000);
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS animation to run this slide show by chance?

Comment: If you are using the setInterval, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278007/1533592

Comment: No im not using CSS animation

Comment: You need some mechanism to stop the `setInterval`. You can read more about `clearInterval` here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp. Also here a SO answer that describes another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24725066

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting a variable, we will call it `pause`, to ***false*** and then run a conditional  inside your `setTimeout()` that checks if it is ***false*** => `if(!paused){ //run code }`.

**Handle the ***paused*** variable due to what state your button is in when it is pressed ==> `e.target`**

You create a function that passes in your event target of a `pause/play` button when it is clicked. In that function you check the value of your `pause/play` button, you can use a `dataset` to toggle `0` or `1` / `on` or `off` / `true` or `false` on click and change the value of your `pause` variable due to what that `dataset` is set to on click.

In my example I use **0** and **1** in the `data-id` attribute => `dataset.id` in JS, with a conditional that checks that value => `if (e.target.dataset.id === '0'){ //set paused to true }else{ // set paused to false }`. Within the conditional I also set the textContent of the button and the `dataset.id` value as well.

Then each time you press the pause button the setInteral freezes as it is looking for paused to not be set to false => `if (!paused){ // run code for setInterval }`.

Below is a simply JS setInterval that increments a number by one every millisecond. We can pause and play it using the function and event listener as described above.

```js
const display = document.getElementById('display')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

let paused = false;
let i = 1;

function checkBool(e) {
  if (e.target.dataset.id === '0') {
    e.target.dataset.id = '1'
    btn.textContent = 'Play'
    paused = true;
  }else{
    e.target.dataset.id = '0'
    btn.textContent = 'Pause'
    paused = false;
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', checkBool)

const timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (!paused) { //<-- paused is not false
    //<-- run the code your interval handles
    display.textContent = i;
    i++;
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<button class="btn" data-id="0">Pause</button>
```