# How to resume a set timeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on an animation where I had to use `setTimeout` to animate it.

Here is my html for the button "pause" which changes to resume on click:

```
<button type="button" id="pause">Pause</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript code where I am pausing the animation using the `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` function of js.

```
document.getElementById("pause".addEventListener("click",function(){
    toggleText();
  clearTimeout(yT);
  clearTimeout(gT);
  clearTimeout(yTt);
  clearTimeout(rsT);
  clearInterval(sI);
```

I want to resume the animation from that very point where it was paused. I tried some functions suggested in other posts from Mr.Tim in this community but nothing is working out for me so far.

Comment: clearTimeout "cancels" the timeouts, it does not "pause" them. You will need to create them again, so you need to store somewhere the details about that. How were they created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript: pause setTimeout();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout)

Comment: `I created it using the following function:
var timeout= setTimeout(function(){ 
  
//do something
   ; }, 1000);  `

Comment: @KiranManiya Yeah I have tried that aswell but it's not working out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiran linked another question which is probably a good solution for you.

As mentioned, there's no built-in `pauseTimeout` function.

However, a simpler way would be to have an if statement within your `setTimeout`. Something like:

```
let timeoutPaused = false;

setTimeout(function(){
    if (!timeoutPaused) {
        doSomething();
    }
}, 1000)

function toggleTimeout() {
    timeoutPaused = !timeoutPaused;
}
```

Then you can just call `toggleTimeout` when you want to turn it off or on. Plus you don't even need that as a separate function really, I just put it like so for educational purposes.

Comment: Hello so I tried what you suggested, what happens now is whichever state I pause the timer, it restarts from the very first state and hence causes more delay. It doesn't really resumes the timer from the point where it was paused.