# How do I pause and resume multiple setTimeout in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck into something which I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to pause and resume an animation using multiple `setTimeout` as it's clear from the code but it doesn't work for me.I took the code from:
[javascript: pause setTimeout();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout)
I edited the code according to my program but it doesn't seem to work.It just starts the animation from the very first state for e.g I paused at `var gT=setTimeout` but it starts from `var yT=setTimeout`
My code looks like this:

```
var start, remaining;

    
    function pause() {
        window.clearTimeout(yT);
        window.clearTimeout(gT);
        remaining -= Date.now() - start;
    };

    function resume() {
        start = Date.now();
        window.clearTimeout(yT);
        window.clearTimeout(gT);
        yT = window.setTimeout(function(){
            all();
            loop();
        }, remaining);
        gT = window.setTimeout(function(){
            all();
            loop();
        }, remaining);


    };

pause();
resume();
```

Comment: Aren't you setting a value for the start and the reaming variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and set remaining and start separately.

```
var start_yT,start_gT, remaining_yT, remaining_gT;

    
    function pause() {
        window.clearTimeout(yT);
        window.clearTimeout(gT);
        remaining_yT -= Date.now() - start_yT;
        remaining_gT -= Date.now() - start_gT;
    };

    function resume() {
        start = Date.now();
        window.clearTimeout(yT);
        window.clearTimeout(gT);
        yT = window.setTimeout(function(){
            all();
            loop();
        }, remaining_yT);
        gT = window.setTimeout(function(){
            all();
            loop();
        }, remaining_gT);


    };

pause();
resume();
```

And if you need to do with more advance version of pause/resume, this is the
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout) . This create each timer separately runtime as we did manually.

Comment: I just have a question. Where does the start_yT/start_gT takes the value from? Should it be the variable for setTimeout?

Comment: Hello, so I tried what you suggested but still the problem is the same like I mentioned in the description. The problem is animation starts from the very first state when I resume it.

Comment: also you may try with removing start from this "remaining -= Date.now() - start;" => "remaining -= Date.now()"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I am not allowed to share the code online.

Comment: The link that you suggested finally worked out for me. Thank you so much.