# Timed message witch pickup command discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I need to make an automatic message that sends every 15 minutes, to be able to "collect" the balls. The point is when using the `pickup` command, delete the message and if the player has collected the `pickup` command, start the timer back for 15 minutes.

```js
    client.on("message", message => {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setColor("RANDOM")
                  .setTitle(``)
                  .setImage(takemoney[Math.round(Math.random() * (takemoney.length - 1))])
                setTimeout(function() {
                  message.channel.send(`Lying on the floor ${balls}, use ;;pick to pick it! `, embed)
                  }, 900000);
              })
```

How to stop the timer before using the `pickup` command and resume the timer after using it?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: How to stop the timer before using the pick command and resume the timer after using it

Comment: Here's some info on how to pause and resume timers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout