# Pause on hover in a photoslider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a photo slider using HTML, CSS and JS. It has an autoplay function, navigation arrows and dots. The direction of the slide animation is reversed based on the corresponding arrows/dots, and the timer is reset on each slide. I'm currently trying to add a "pause on hover" function, but it doesn't pause the timer but resets the timer.

For example, the slider speed is currently set to 3000ms. When the cursor hovers over `.elements` at 2000ms, I need it to pause the timer. And when the cursor leaves `.elements`, I need the timer to count down the remaining 1000ms and then move on to the next slide. Could you please help me with this?

```js
var timeout;

function setDirection(d) {
  document.querySelector('.slider').style.setProperty('--direction', d);
}
setDirection(1);
var slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
var sliderDots = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0].children);
var sliderContents = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("elements")[0].children);
var sliderArrowLeft = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-left")[0];
var sliderArrowRight = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-right")[0];
var sliderSpeed = 3000,
  currentSlide = 0,
  currentActive = 0,
  sliderTimer = 0;

let elements = document.querySelector('.elements');
elements.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
});

elements.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide);
});

function playSlide(slide, d) {
  if (!(d === undefined)) {
    direction = d;
    setDirection(d);

    // Force it forwards after it's done:
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      setDirection(1);
    }, 1000)
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < sliderDots.length; k++) {
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("active");
    sliderContents[k].classList.remove("inactive");
    sliderDots[k].classList.remove("active");
  }
  if (slide < 0) {
    slide = currentSlide = sliderContents.length - 1;
  }
  if (slide > sliderContents.length - 1) {
    slide = currentSlide = 0;
  }
  if (currentActive != currentSlide) {
    sliderContents[currentActive].classList.add("inactive");
  }
  sliderContents[slide].classList.add("active");
  sliderDots[slide].classList.add("active");
  currentActive = currentSlide;
  clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
  sliderTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
  }, sliderSpeed)
}
sliderArrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide -= 1, -1);
})
sliderArrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playSlide(currentSlide += 1, 1);
})
for (var l = 0; l < sliderDots.length; l++) {
  sliderDots[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let d = sliderDots.indexOf(this) - currentSlide
    playSlide(currentSlide = sliderDots.indexOf(this), Math.sign(d));
  })
}
playSlide(currentSlide);
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 0;
}

.dots {
  height: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.dot.active {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.elements {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(0px);
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.image.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.inactive {
  z-index: -3;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image.active span {
  animation: show .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.image.inactive span {
  animation: hide .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(calc(var(--direction)*100%));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(calc(-1*var(--direction)*100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="contents">
    <div class="arrow-left">prev</div>
    <div class="arrow-right">next</div>
    <div class="dots">
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
      <li class="dot"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="elements">
      <div class="image"><span>image 1</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 2</span></div>
      <div class="image"><span>image 3</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you will need to _create_ a new timeout  then, when the mouse cursor leaves the element again. Create a new `Date` instance when you start the timer, and a new one when you hover the element - and calculate the difference in ms. 3000ms minus that difference, are the value you need to set your new timeout with.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969475/javascript-pause-settimeout

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. In theory they might be the solution I'm looking for, but in practice I still can't manage to adapt the method to my own slider :(

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the css according to you, I have written some css for both of us to understand so that the result looks healthy and clean to solve your question. I am giving you a slider ready. I provide you the code of HTML, CSS and JS.

```js
var timeout;
        var sliderDots = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dot"));
        var sliderContents = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("image"));
        var sliderArrowLeft = document.querySelector(".arrow-left");
        var sliderArrowRight = document.querySelector(".arrow-right");
        var sliderSpeed = 3000;
        var currentSlide = 0;
        var sliderTimer = 0;

        var elements = document.querySelector('.elements');
        var isPaused = false;

        elements.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
            isPaused = true;
        });

        elements.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
            isPaused = false;
            sliderTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                playSlide(currentSlide + 1);
            }, sliderSpeed);
        });

        function playSlide(slide) {
            for (var k = 0; k < sliderDots.length; k++) {
                sliderContents[k].classList.remove("active");
                sliderDots[k].classList.remove("active");
            }
            if (slide < 0) {
                slide = currentSlide = sliderContents.length - 1;
            }
            if (slide > sliderContents.length - 1) {
                slide = currentSlide = 0;
            }
            // Update the currentSlide
            currentSlide = slide;
            // Add the "active" class to the current slide and dot
            sliderContents[currentSlide].classList.add("active");
            sliderDots[currentSlide].classList.add("active");

            if (!isPaused) {
                clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
                sliderTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    playSlide(currentSlide + 1);
                }, sliderSpeed);
            }
        }

        sliderArrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
            playSlide(currentSlide - 1);
        });

        sliderArrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
            playSlide(currentSlide + 1);
        });

        for (var l = 0; l < sliderDots.length; l++) {
            sliderDots[l].addEventListener("click", function () {
                playSlide(sliderDots.indexOf(this));
            });
        }

        playSlide(currentSlide);
```

```css
body,
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* Global styles */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        /* Slider container */
        .slider {
            position: relative;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        /* Slider contents */
        .contents {
            position: relative;
        }

        /* Slide images */
        .image {
            display: none;
        }

        .image.active {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Slide navigation arrows */
        .arrow-left,
        .arrow-right {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 8px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            color: white;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .arrow-left {
            left: 10px;
        }

        .arrow-right {
            right: 10px;
        }

        /* Slide navigation dots */
        .dots {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .dot {
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            margin: 0 6px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }

        .dot.active {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Slide</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="contents">
            <div class="arrow-left">prev</div>
            <div class="arrow-right">next</div>
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="dot"></li>
                <li class="dot"></li>
                <li class="dot"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="elements">
                <div class="image active"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/aaa/fff&text=1" alt="Image 1"></div>
                <div class="image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/aaa/fff&text=2" alt="Image 2"></div>
                <div class="image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/aaa/fff&text=3" alt="Image 3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Could you please add the rest of my codes, so everyone can see your solution in action?

Comment: I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for it. Once your solution works stable, I'll click on the accepted answer button gladly.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but mouse-hover resets the timer in your code -- it doesn't pause. So your method does the same thing with the code I provided, and sliding direction function seems missing

Comment: I'm thankful for your time and effort, but mouse-hover still "resets" the timer, not pause... Additionally, my rotation determining function and ltr/rtl sliding animations seems missing... When adding a new feature, I think it's important to avoid breaking the existing features since it'll not be easy to fix them later.